# Exam class, question number jumps in when using algorithmic environment

Tags: exam, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I'm using the `algorithmic` package to write pseudocode in my homework assignments. I use the exam class to use the `question` environment it provides. But now I noticed that as soon as I use the `algorithmic` environment at the beginning of a question the number jumps a bit to the right, instead of nicely aligning with the other question numbers. Of course I'd prefer if all the question numbers would be on one vertical line. Below a MWE and the way that that looks like.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question 

        \question
            \begin{algorithmic}
                insert algorithm pseudocode here
            \end{algorithmic}

        \question
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, I'm using TexStudio on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You example is a bit too minimal: The statements in the `algorithmic` environment should be preceded by a keyword, in the simplest case by `\STATE`. When you put this in front of your text, the indentations are ok.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question Question 1
  \question Question 2
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \STATE insert algorithm pseudocode here
    \PRINT something
    \end{algorithmic}
  \question Question 3
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, how could I forget to add that? Thanks for pointing that out.